# Assign Lazy<T> to T

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I have a domain object like:

```
public class Domain
{
    public HeavyType Property {get;set;}
}
```

And Property is very time consuming to load, since i have around 400 Domain objects, i'd like to omit it at first. I could use something like

```
public class Domain
{
    private Lazy<HeavyType> _lazy;
    public HeavyType Property {get{return _lazy.Value;} set{_lazy = new Lazy(...);}}
}
```

But in the spirit of separation of concerns i'd like to do something like this:

```
Domain d = new Domain();
d.Property = new Lazy(() => ...);
```

I already searched the internet and found duck typing, dynamic proxies etc..
But nothing really suited my needs. Is there something i overlooked?

Comment: In general, no you can't do that. A somewhat common pattern would be to have a getter-only property and a `SetPropertyFactory(Func<HeavyType> valueFactory)` method

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying about the separation of concerns. How are you loading the rest of the domain data that isn't taking a long time to load?